# Rounding up a double using Math inputs

Tags: java, math, methods

I have to make this method round up a double which is fine but I need it to only round up the first number after the first decimal.

Example 83.2839783214 would be 83.3 here is the code I have so far I can't seem to figure out how exactly to implement it.

public double getPercentFull(){

```
double percent;

double p = (storage / capacity) * 100;

percent = (double)Math.round(p);
```

return percent;

Comment: The other post  that is a duplicate doesn't answer my questions. Doing this for a class and have to write methods without importing.

Comment: `((double) Math.round(x * 10)) / 10` which of course has no exact precision, floating point only approximates real numbers with a sum of (negative) powers of 2.

Comment: This worked thank you :D! After fooling around with it I found out that the more 0's you add the more decimals are displayed as well.

Comment: Aaah, improved on the solution. Mind that 1,000,000 * 0.1 will not exactly be 100,000.0. For financial things use BigDecimal.